# How to get ng-bind="property_address" using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
{
   "agreement":{
      "property_address":"B-99 Sector 44",
      "property_city":"Noida",
      "property_state":"Uttar Pradesh",
      "property_pincode":"201201",
      "agreement_place":"",
      "agreement_date":"",
      "monthly_rent":"10000",
      "rent_due_date":"5",
      "maintenance_fee":"500",
      "security_deposit":"",
      "renewal_rent_increment":"5",
      "area":"1200",
      "renting_purpose":"Residential",
      "electricity_bill":"Tenant",
      "pets":"Allowed",
      "sub_lease_property":"Allowed",
      "agreement_type":"",
      "property_type":"House",
      "user_type":"",
      "agreement_starting_date":"26 September 2016",
      "agreement_starting_duration":"11",
      "agreement_end_date":"26 August 2017",
      "delivery_address":"Tenant Address",
      "lock_in_period":"2",
      "witness1":"",
      "witness2":"",
      "areaunit":"Sq. Feet"
   },
   "landlord":{
      "name":"Sumit",
      "age":"22",
      "gender":"Male",
      "father_name":"RK Gupta",
      "address":"B-99 Sector 44",
      "city":"Noida",
      "state":"Uttar Pradesh",
      "pincode":"201201"
   },
   "tenant":{
      "name":"Nitish",
      "age":"29",
      "gender":"Male",
      "father_name":"BP Sharma",
      "address":"H.no 78, Sector 2 Chandigarh",
      "city":"HARYANA",
      "state":"Haryana",
      "pincode":"121001"
   },
   "payment":{
      "total_amount":449
   },
   "user":{
      "name":"",
      "email":"",
      "phone":""
   },
   "stamp_price":"",
   "user_id":"86",
   "step":"4"
}
```

Comment: if you want an answer you have to be more specific, what is your question ? show the code you try

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
  </head>

  <body>
     
    
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <div ng-bind="data.agreement.property_address"/>
        <div ng-bind="data.landlord.name"/>
        <div ng-bind="data.landlord.age"/>
    </div>
    
     
    
    
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>

Comment: It looks like you have/had more information to add to this question. Please do so, if only to prevent the question from being put "on hold". You have two off-topic questions so far, and if you ask too many of these, it could result in an automatic ban on new questions. Please also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

a working example : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/bwNCBH3aiNzQ9ubKuEQS?p=preview

in the controller :

```
$scope.data = {
    "agreement": {
        "property_address": "B-99 Sector 44",
        "property_city": "Noida",
        "property_state": "Uttar Pradesh",
    },
    "user": {
        "name": "ajay",
        "email": "ajay@hotmail.com",
        "phone": "0123456789"
    },
}
```

in the view :

```
<div ng-bind="data.agreement.property_address"/>
```

if you only want to display the information don't use ng-bind:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
   address :  {{data.agreement.property_address}}<br>
   city :  {{data.agreement.property_city}}<br>
   state: {{data.agreement.property_state}}<br>
     <br>
   name : {{data.user.name}}<br>
  email :  {{data.user.email}}<br>
   phone: {{data.user.phone}}<br> 
</div>
```